# Querying a repeated property by count in NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is there an efficient mechanism for querying by the number of items in a repeated property in NDB?

I'd like to do something like:

```
Class.query(class.repeated_property.count == 2)
```

but of course this doesn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Specifically, you can use [ComputedProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) to automatically store the count, e.g.

```
class X(ndb.Model):
  prop = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
  prop_count = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: len(e.prop))

X.query(X.prop_count == 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no len query semantic in GQL, you will need to have a sperate property for the length of the list and query on it.